# ListView doesn't render results but for loop does

Tags: android, angular, listview, nativescript

I have an Observable Array of objects which I use in my listview to render asynchronously. The problem is that my ListView does not work correctly. When I get the results the list does only fill in blank rows initially, even if I can see I get a response of objects from my HTTP request.

Now if I click on the button to switch applications on the android emulator but then go back right away to the app, the list is now filled.

Or if I go to another page/activity in the app and go back, the list works as it should. So something is wrong with the rendering. Question is what?

If I do not use a listview and use an ng-container with *ngFor on the items, the same way I do with the listview, it works perfectly. The results prints right away.

Below is code from my component.
This doesn't work properly:

```
   <GridLayout>
                            <ListView id="searchList" [items]="responseItems$ | async" class="list-group">
                                <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
  <GridLayout class="list-group-item" [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
<Label textWrap="true"  [text]='item?.English'></Label>

                                    </GridLayout>
                                </ng-template>
                            </ListView>
      </GridLayout>
```

This works as expected:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor = "let v of (responseItems$ | async); let i = index;">
                <Label [text]="i"></Label>    
                <Label style="background:#eaeaea;" (tap)="wordClickSimple(i)" textWrap="true" [text]='v?.English'></Label>
            </ng-container>
```

Comment: I'm using almost every time a ListView with async pipe, so I can confirm it works. If you can share a Playground example where the issue can be reproduced, I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: @Manoj great to hear and thank you! I'll check that out about playground, never used it before so.

Comment: @Manoj I have not yet done a playground example. But if you want check out my code please do so :) at https://github.com/mosesweb/nativescriptTesting/tree/master/src/app/home Check out the home.component.html, home.component.ts and user.service (method: searchWord at row: 266). I am still clueless why this doesn't work..

Comment: Got this solved by adding *ngIf="responseItems$ | async; else loading" in the ListView. It just go rendered too fast without my list object properties printed out in time apparently.